# Google colab: Read .xlsx file in from Github pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

from Google Colab, I am trying to create a df from a xlsx file I have on a Github repo.
As url I take the permalink from Github, the repo is public and account in connected to Colab

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!'

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try this: `xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=your_bytes_string)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is due to the URL that you are using.

You should try to do this to see what is returned by `request.get`.

```py
url = "https://github.com/your-user-name/your-repo-name/blob/main/data/raw/your-file-name.xlsx"

import requests
from pprint import pprint

response = requests.get(url)
pprint(response.content)
```

It is an HTML page. This is not what you want.

There are a couple of things you can do to solve this. This medium post [here](https://medium.com/towards-entrepreneurship/importing-a-csv-file-from-github-in-a-jupyter-notebook-e2c28e7e74a5) might be useful.

However, one simple thing is to use an URL like the example below:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your-username/name-of-the-repository/master/name-of-the-file.xlsx
```

I've already tried this and it works.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your-username/name-of-the-repository/master/name-of-the-file.xlsx"

response = requests.get(url)

dest = 'local-file.xlsx'

with open(dest, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)

frame = pd.read_excel(dest)

frame.head()
```

Conclusion: change your URL.

Answer (score 2):

Please use link from `"view raw"`. for my file I use below url

[image: Pls use link from view raw]

```
url = 'https://github.com/mehadisaki/Sales-Forecasting-model-development-/blob/main/TV%20Delivery_2016-2022.xlsx?raw=true'
db=pd.read_excel(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Google Colab one thing you could do is use the `wget` command, like this.

```
!wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your-username/name-of-the-repository/master/name-of-the-file.xlsx"
```

Comment: Do you mind deleting this and editing this into your previous answer? Posting multiple answer to the same question is discouraged.